# Gantt chart on Excel - Conditional Formatting based on the number of days for a task which are in a given month

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, gantt-chart

I'm trying to build a Gantt Chart in Excel where I could conditionally fortmat cells to reflect the number of days a task has on a given month.

For example, today is 24-oct-19. A task starting on 11-oct-19 and ending on 08-nov-19 has 20 days on October and 8 days in November. I need to conditionally format a cell on the task row, October column, to be painted in a proportion given by 20/31. I should format similarly the same row, November column.

None of the many Gantt charts I found online could make it. Could you please give advice on how could I do this?

I'm also attaching a sketch.

Thank you!

[Gantt chart with next 12 months](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cu9PV.png)

Comment: Charting is a lot more manual in Excel. How many tasks in your real case? It could be a pain to do it for hundreds of tasks in Gantt Charts...

Comment: Hi terry. Not many. I have around 12 projects with a number of tasks ranging from 10 to 20 each. Is there any other free tool you would recommend me to try?

Comment: There is a tip here https://www.techrepublic.com/forums/discussions/is-there-any-way-in-excel-to-color-a-cell-proportionally/ about using Alt-219 to establish a bar in a cell (which could be made any length and any colour) - I wonder if that would help? I wasn't quite clear if you wanted to show a length in proportion to the number of days, or just a colour (like red a lot of days, green a few days?)

Comment: Also Alt-176,177 and 178 to get different shading http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a proof of concept (not very aesthetically pleasing because of padding round cells, but this can be fixed).

I just wanted to see if you could get a reasonable chart using basic string functions to get a bar in the right position in each cell:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT($A$5,ROUND((MAX(D$1,$B6)-D$1)/DAY(EOMONTH(D$1,0))*10,0))&LEFT($A$3,ROUND((MIN($C6,EOMONTH(D$1,0))-MAX(D$1,$B6)+1)/DAY(EOMONTH(D$1,0))*10,0)),"")
```

[image]

Slightly more pleasing appearance - the trick is to centre the text in the cell, but then you need to include spaces to the right where necessary (e.g. in cell E6) to make it work:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT($A$5,ROUND((MAX(D$1,$B6)-D$1)/DAY(EOMONTH(D$1,0))*10,0))
&LEFT($A$3,ROUND((MIN($C6,EOMONTH(D$1,0))-MAX(D$1,$B6)+1)/DAY(EOMONTH(D$1,0))*10,0))
&LEFT($A$5,ROUND((EOMONTH(D$1,0)-MIN(EOMONTH(D$1,0),$C6))/DAY(EOMONTH(D$1,0))*10,0)),"")
```

[image]

To get fixed character size, I have set the area where the bars are to use Courier font, and chosen a suitable column width.

Comment: Hi Tom. Very clever, thank you. Did you need to manually align the text in the cells to make the bars of consecutive months touch? Maybe I need to write a macro to do it. Moreover, You said the trick is to centre the cells and add spaces. Why? That would leave large gaps between bars in the same line.

Comment: OK it's a bit counter-intuitive. When I googled 'remove cell padding in Excel' the advice seemed to be to format the cells to be centred horizontally. This does seem to work, but if you look at a cell like E6, the string is three characters long left-adjusted ███  But if you centre that, it will look something like this ▒▒▒███▒▒▒ (where ▒▒▒ represents spaces) which is no good at all. So you have to start off with ███▒▒▒▒▒▒ and centre that, which gives the right effect but makes the formula a bit longer.

Comment: Got it. The bars are now neatly placed. Thank you!